# Can't feed my model with my image data tensor

Tags: c++, deep-learning, pytorch

**cv::Mat image to Tensor function**

```
auto ToTensor(cv::Mat img, bool show_output = false, bool unsqueeze = false, int unsqueeze_dim = 0)
    {
        std::cout << "image shape: " << img.size() << std::endl;
        at::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(img.data, { 1,3,img.rows, img.cols }, at::kByte);
    
        if (unsqueeze)
        {
            tensor_image.unsqueeze_(unsqueeze_dim);
            std::cout << "tensors new shape: " << tensor_image.sizes() << std::endl;
        }
    
        if (show_output)
        {
            std::cout << tensor_image.slice(2, 0, 1) << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "tensor shape: " << tensor_image.sizes() << std::endl;
        return tensor_image;
    }
```

**Main part**

```
int main() {
    
    string filename = ".../torch_model/scriptmodule2.pt";
    auto model =torch::jit::load(filename);
    cout << "Model good to go !!!!"<<endl;
    Mat img = imread(".../image.bmp");
    int down_width = 224;
    int down_height = 224;
    Mat img1;
    resize(img, img1, Size(down_width, down_height), INTER_LINEAR);
    
   
    at::Tensor tensor1 = ToTensor(img1);
    
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(tensor1);
    model.eval();
    auto output = model.forward(inputs);
           

 }
```

**in Pytorch documentation there is :
but It doesn't work when I made my own image tensor's shapes just like this example**

```
// Create a vector of inputs.
std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, 3, 224, 224}));

// Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
std::cout << output.slice(/*dim=*/1, /*start=*/0, /*end=*/5) << '\n';
```

**when I use this example tensor then does it works without problem?**

My images Output :

```
Model good to go !!!!
image shape: [224 x 224]
tensor shape: [1, 3, 224, 224]

C:\Users\murat\source\repos\torch_model\x64\Release\torch_model.exe (process 19172) exited with code -1073740791.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Example tensor output :

```
Model good to go !!!!
image shape: [224 x 224]
tensor shape: [1, 3, 224, 224]
-4.6431  5.9491
[ CPUFloatType{1,2} ]

C:\Users\murat\source\repos\torch_model\x64\Release\torch_model.exe (process 9596) exited with code 0.
```

Comment: I've been dealing with this for a day. Please help there are no documents anymore, which I did not look at.

Comment: Can you paste the outputs you get? Are you getting pytorch errors?

Comment: Also, why do you need `IValue` why not just use `at::Tensor`?

Comment: When I use direct my tensor of my image then visual studio gives me a warning, //at::Tensor tensor1 = ToTensor(img1);                //                                                                          auto output = model.forward(tensor1); @Unlikus

Comment: please add the exact wording of the warning to your question.

Comment: `at::Tensor tensor1 = ToTensor(img1); auto output = model.forward(tensor1); `  then says : no suitable use-defined conversion from "at::tensor" to "std::vector<c10::IValue,std::alloctar<c10::Value>> exists

Comment: your error message says your compiler cannot convert a `at::Tensor` into a `std::vector<torch::jit::IValue>`.
Also in your question you dont have the line `auto output = model.forward(tensor1);`
Instead you try to pass a `std::vector` to `model.forward`.
Also please edit your question and add all error messages and indicate which are compiler errors and which are errors at runtime.

Comment: @Unlikus ah sorry i did write wrong. I am already passing a vector with this `std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;`
 **inputs.push_back(inputs);**                                                                                    `auto output = model.forward(inputs);`                       then 
editor gives me thisno suitable use-defined conversion from "at::tensor" to "std::vector<c10::IValue,std::alloctar<c10::Value>> exists

Comment: This is a compile time error, how were you able to execute this and get the results you edited into your question?
`inputs.push_back(inputs);` cant work

Comment: @Unlikus I'm totally done with today bro that's the second time that I'm writing wrong. That was actually  `inputs.push_back(tensor1);`                                                             How can I take the output for one image using my loaded model ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function and feed my model and It worked.

```
torch::Tensor CVtoTensor(cv::Mat img,int unsqueeze_dim = 0) {
    cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size{ img.rows, img.cols }, 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
    cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    auto img_tensor = torch::from_blob(img.data, { img.rows, img.cols, 3 }, torch::kByte);
    img_tensor = img_tensor.permute({ 2, 0, 1 }).toType(torch::kFloat).div_(255);
    std::cout << "tensor shape: " << img_tensor.sizes() << std::endl;
    
    
    
    img_tensor.unsqueeze_(unsqueeze_dim);
    std::cout << "tensors new shape: " << img_tensor.sizes() << std::endl;
    return img_tensor;
}
```